# Cannot write to /storage/emulated/0 after nandroid restore (even as root)

Tags: root-access, internal-storage, nandroid

On  my rooted Motorola Moto G 2014 LTE I can no longer access the directories under `/storage/emulated/0/`, such as Download, Documents, Ringtones.

Using a file explorer, without root access, I just get access denied when trying to open the folder; with root access, I can open the folder but I am unable to write in it. Folder permissions seems ok (770, owned by `root` and group `sdcard_r`).

Using a terminal emulator, trying to do an `ll` inside the folder (as root) returns `opendir failed, Permission denied`.

What I did prior to the problem was:

- unlock the bootloader, install TRWP recovery
- root
- install various apps (including Link2SD to move some apps to the SD card)
- perform a nandroid backup
- trying to flash Xposed: I had some issues here after reboot, so I restored the nandroid backup

Another thing to notice: after the nandroid restore, an app installed before making the backup (FX File explorer) was missing.

**EDIT**: I solved with a full wipe (not just factory reset) and restoring again the previous backup.

Comment: @Firelord I've read from various sources that the "fix permission" tool is deprecated and actually does more harm than good on Lollipop. In the end I just solved with a full wipe and another nandroid restore, and the problem was gone.